# search function not working - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and trying to implement a search function with simple form to filter out availabilities results. After I press search button, it still stays on the same page and not running the search function in the controller. The permitted is false. I'm wondering why this might occur. Is there anything wrong with the search_params I wrote? 
Rails version is 6.0.2.1.

views/availabilities/_searchform.html.erb

```
<form>
    <div id="aDiv">
        <%= simple_form_for :search, :url => search_rides_result_path, :method => :get do |f| %>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <%= f.input :start_city, label: 'Start City', class: "form-control", error: 'Start address is mandatory, please specify one' %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <%= f.input :start_street_address, label: 'Start Street Address', class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <%= f.input :end_city, label: 'Destination City', class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <%= f.input :end_street_address, label: 'Destionation Street Address', class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <%= f.input :trip_time, as: :datetime, inline_label: 'Yes, remember me', class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <%= f.input :lowest_acceptable_price, label: 'Expected Price', class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
        </div>
            <%= f.submit "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</form>
```

routes.rb file.

```
  get 'search_rides', to: "availabilities#index"
  get 'search_rides_result', to: "availabilities#search"
```

availabilities_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @availabilities = Availability.unmatched
  end

  def search
    @availabilities = Availability.unmatched.search(search_params[:start_city])
  end

  def search_params
    params.require(:search).permit(:start_city, :start_street_address, :end_city, :end_street_address, :trip_time, :lowest_acceptable_price)
  end
```

models/availability.rb

```
class Availability < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users, :through => :posts
    has_one :request
    scope :unmatched, ->{ where(matched_request_id: -1) }

    def self.search (params)
        puts "start searching"
        results = city_matches(start_city, end_city, params[:start_city], params[:end_city]) 
        return nil unless results
        results
    end
```

Comment: are you seeing the get request come in? What do the params look like in the logs?

Comment: @DanHilton If I type something in the form, the parameters are like this: Parameters: {"search"=>{"start_city"=>"waltham", "start_street_address"=>"some street", "end_city"=>"waltham", "end_street_address"=>"other street", "trip_time(1i)"=>"2020", "trip_time(2i)"=>"3", "trip_time(3i)"=>"25", "trip_time(4i)"=>"18", "trip_time(5i)"=>"05", "lowest_acceptable_price"=>"5"}, "commit"=>"Search"}
 I think the get request works as these params are appended to the url. However, anything in the search function is not executed.

Comment: I see. I wonder if it has to do with your search.html.erb template (since that form action is hitting your search action). Usually with search, I've seen the search form path submitting to the index action. This way the controller can determine whether to do any necessary filtering, but the view is the same

Comment: @DanHilton Thanks! Let me see if it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using 2 different methods for search, try combining both in index method. Your index method will now look as follows:

```
def index
  if params[:search]
    @availabilities = Availability.unmatched.search(search_params[:start_city])
  else
    @availabilities = Availability.unmatched
  end
end
```

Change the form `url` to `search_rides_path`. This way search results will be rendered in same view upon form submission.